# Any way to deploy a solana program with an offline/cold authority?

Tags: smartcontracts, solana

The CLI command (`solana program deploy`) doesn't [seem](https://docs.solana.com/offline-signing) to permit offline signing.

Is there any other way to deploy a solana program without putting the contract authority on an internet-connected computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *almost* possible. You'll need to follow the instructions for deploying to a buffer before performing the upgrade in one transaction.

Essentially, you have a hot key write the program buffer with `solana program write-buffer`, and then the upgrade authority only authorizes the upgrade transaction with `solana program deploy --program-id <> --buffer <>`.

It wouldn't be a lot of work to add the `sign_only` flag to the `deploy` command to have the last bit done offline.  Feel free to submit an issue for that! https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues

More information at: https://docs.solana.com/cli/deploy-a-program#using-an-intermediary-buffer-account

Comment: Thanks, and good idea: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/23975